# I want to specify the path of sn.exe file, but which to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, sn

I want to specify the path of `sn.exe` file to some program but I don't know which one would be correct for a `.NET 2.0` project as there are multiple folders in the `Microsoft SDKs` that have `sn.exe` file.

After `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin` path, I get multiple folders like `NETFX 4.x.x tools` each of which contains the `sn.exe`. Which one to choose especially for a `.NET 2.0` project.

Comment: 2.0 is too long ago to remember accurately, 14 years are a lot of dog-years.  IIRC, VS2005 shipped with SDK version 6.0.  It just doesn't matter, all of these versions do the same thing.  Try to not get stuck on ancient versions of free software that is no longer supported.